# s3 post signature not matching the AWS documentation example(python)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am trying to reproduce the signature calculated in the following exemple [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html).

The documentation that shows the post signature construction is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html).

Here is my python code that tries to reproduce de step by step for creating the signature (using the same parameters as the example):

```
import hmac
import hashlib

secret_access_key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
aws_region = 'us-east-1'
aws_service = 's3'
date_str = '20151229'
encoded_policy = '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'

def digest(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key.encode('UTF-8'), msg.encode('UTF-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

date_key = digest(date_str, ('AWS4' + secret_access_key))
date_region_key = digest(date_key, aws_region)
date_region_service_key = digest(date_region_key, aws_service)
signing_key = digest(date_region_service_key, 'aws4_request')

signature = digest(signing_key, encoded_policy)

print(signature)
```

This code returns me the following signature:

```
6f86ebce05110fadcd2972035d7dee85e120171012d340467a518f37db41d253
```

But is expected to return this signature (as shown in the aws example):

```
8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `digest()` function returns hex.  The date, region, service, and signing keys should all be raw binary blobs, not hex strings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't realy realized what's the problem with my code, but after many doc readings and many attempts, I found a code that helped me and took me to the right signature.

Here's the code:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import codecs

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(("AWS4" + key).encode("utf-8"), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, "aws4_request")
    return kSigning

key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
dateStamp = '20151229'
regionName = 'us-east-1'
serviceName = 's3'
string_to_sign = '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'

signing_key = getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName)

signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

print(signature)
```

I got this snipet from this page, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html).

Hope this could help anyone with the same problem.